# Sending some lines of string to server (UDP) in java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram, udpclient

I try to send a string consist of some lines in one datagram packet from my client to server ,my problem is when I send the string only first line will send to the server ,I want to send one line then after 10 second send another line and another, how can I solve it???
this is my client code for sending string :

```
    String msge="null";
    String atCurrentLine = null;
     try (BufferedReader cl = new BufferedReader(
     new FileReader("Client1.txt"))) { 
     while ((atCurrentLine = cl.readLine()) != null) {
            msge=atCurrentLine;
    System.out.println(msge);

        } 


    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } 


    DatagramSocket skt = null;
    try {
      skt = new DatagramSocket();
      byte[] b = msge.getBytes();
      InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");   
      int cl = 6700;                       
      DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(b,b.length,host,cl);  
      skt.send(request);
```

and this code for server to receive:

```
     DatagramSocket skt = null;
    try {
       skt = new DatagramSocket(6700);
       byte [] buffer = new byte[1000];
        while (true) {                
          DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
          skt.receive(request);

          String [] arrayMsg = (new String(request.getData())).split("       ");
          sms=arrayMsg[0];
          System.out.println("received from client :"+arrayMsg[0]);
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide us with your code? I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Comment: UDP doesn't care what data is in a datagram. It is just an arbitrary payload. So, if you are missing some data in a given datagram, it is because you didn't put the data in the datagram properly to begin with. Please show your actual code that is preparing and sending the datagram, and the code that is receiving and parsing it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for reply i added my code in the question .

Comment: Welcome :) You should see the difference between the operator "=" and "+=" when you put a line into your "msge" variable

Comment: @adrienolivier yah you are right i uesd it , but when i send "msge" variable all line send together( i want to send my line one after one ) i have this problem